# How to install both MATLAB MCR and the dotnet runtime in a Docker container?

Tags: c#, matlab, docker, .net-core, matlab-compiler

I am trying to create a Docker container where I can use `dotnet` to run a C# program that loads a MATLAB Runtime ([MCR](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html)) DLL to process some data. (.net core 3.1, MATLAB 2014b)

I have created an image based on the official dotnet image for Ubuntuthat installs the MATLAB's MCR runtime in accordance with an [example](https://github.com/flywheel-apps/matlab-mcr/blob/master/2014b/Dockerfile) I've found online. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-focal 
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y \
    unzip \
    xorg \
    wget \
    curl && \   
    mkdir /mcr-install && \
    mkdir /opt/mcr && \
    cd /mcr-install && \
    wget http://ssd.mathworks.com/supportfiles/downloads/R2014b/deployment_files/R2014b/installers/glnxa64/MCR_R2014b_glnxa64_installer.zip && \
    unzip -q MCR_R2014b_glnxa64_installer.zip && \
    ./install -destinationFolder /opt/mcr -agreeToLicense yes -mode silent && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf mcr-install

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/mcr/v84/runtime/glnxa64:/opt/mcr/v84/bin/glnxa64:/opt/mcr/v84/sys/os/glnxa64:/opt/mcr/v84/extern/bin/glnxa64
```

When I run the container interactively and try to run `dotnet` in it I get this error:

```
❯ docker run -it dotnet-mcr:0.2 /bin/bash
root@1e15419d3fee:/# dotnet --info
Failed to load ���, error: /opt/mcr/v84/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/3.1.10/libhostfxr.so)
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/3.1.10/libhostfxr.so failed
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370
```

It seems that the last line in my `Dockerfile` - the one that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - is essential for the MCR runtime but disrupts the `dotnet` executable.

**How can I work around this issue?**

Note: As @jdweng commented below, upgrading to a more recent version of MATLAB could likely solve the issue by aligning the versions of the clashing DLLs. I would appreciate, if possible, a solution that does not involve upgrading.

Comment: The version of matlab that you compile the dll must be the same version as the installed runtime version of matlab.  The docker installation must be installing and different runtime version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jdweng wrote in a comment to my question - The solution is to use .Net and MATLAB versions that depend on the same version of C++ shared objects.

In my case this means .Net Core 3.1 and MATLAB 2020b (v99). Below is the Dockerfile that works for me (again, based on Michael Perry's [example](https://github.com/flywheel-apps/matlab-mcr/blob/master/2014b/Dockerfile)).

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-focal 
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y \
    unzip \
    xorg \
    wget \
    curl && \   
    mkdir /mcr-install && \
    mkdir /opt/mcr && \
    cd /mcr-install && \
    wget https://ssd.mathworks.com/supportfiles/downloads/R2020b/Release/3/deployment_files/installer/complete/glnxa64/MATLAB_Runtime_R2020b_Update_3_glnxa64.zip && \
    unzip -q MATLAB_Runtime_R2020b_Update_3_glnxa64.zip && \
    ./install -destinationFolder /opt/mcr -agreeToLicense yes -mode silent && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf mcr-install

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/mcr/v99/runtime/glnxa64:/opt/mcr/v99/bin/glnxa64:/opt/mcr/v99/sys/os/glnxa64:/opt/mcr/v99/extern/bin/glnxa64
```